# Wcf with ssl and client certificate : request svc succes wcf call returns 403.16

Tags: wcf, certificate, client, ssl-certificate

Configuration:
Iis web app with require ssl and accept client certificates.
Web app contains wcf service. 
Requesting a page from web app works as wel as requesting the wcf svc
Calling wcf from wcf client give 406.13 with same client certificate send.

Same setup works on development and several other production servers.

Checked cert store trusted root for illegal certificates. ( issued by <> issued to )
Applied reg setting schannel (from MS solutions).

How is this possible that browser requests do not fail but wcf requests do?

Must be something iis or windows related as same code works on other machines.

Any way to get more info why it thinks the client certificate is not trusted.
P.s. the wcf service method is never entered ( as my own tracing shows nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218370/3245057) might be of some help. CAPI2 event log is the place where you should find more information why WCF considers the client certificate not trusted. Enable it both on the client side and also on the server side.